# pandas converting Series to DataFrame without the "dtype" information

Tags: pandas, dataframe, series

I have a Series called Sizemode with the following structure:

```
In [1]:Sizemode   
Out[1]: 
0     50000    
1    248000    
dtype: int64
```

and while I am trying to create a dataframe out of it with the following line:

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'Most Frequent Size':[Sizemode]})
```

it writes in one cell in the new "test" dataframe the following:

```
0    50000                                                                             
1    248000dtype: int64
```

Question: how can I create the new dataframe with the following structure?

```
50000, 248000
```

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you want 50000 and 248000 to be in separate columns, or as a list in a single column?

Comment: as a list in the same column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing:

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'Most Frequent Size':[Sizemode]})
```

to

```
test = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Most Frequent Size':", ".join(map(str, Sizemode.values))}, orient="index")
```

`Sizemode` is a `Series` object, but `Sizemode.values` will access the `ndarray` containing the data and will not be split, or include the dtype info when you generate the `DataFrame`.

Comment: thank you. this gives me though the following:   [ 50000 248000].  I want it without [ ] if possible. thanks a lot!

Comment: I've updated the answer to convert the output from a list to a common-separated string.

Comment: "ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index."    Any idea how to tackle this? Thanks a lot

Comment: The edited code will make `Most Frequent Size` the index.  Alternatively you could do this and define your own index.  `test = pd.DataFrame({'Most Frequent Size':", ".join(map(str, Sizemode.values))}, index=[0])`.  Depends what kind of behavior you want.

Comment: brilliant! exactly what I wanted. Thanks vm. appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

`pd.DataFrame({'Most Frequent Size':[str(tuple(Sizemode.values))]})` will construct the dataframe without index error.

`str(tuple(Sizemode.values))` returns the comma-delimited string of values in `Sizemode`.